# Items are in wrong place in Android Studio emulator

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-emulator

I'm new to android studio and this is my first app.
It works correctly but having an issue with the emulator, it shows the button in the wrong place.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.dell_pc.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtyear"
        android:layout_width="193dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter year of birth"
        android:inputType="number"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="129dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="96dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/butage"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:onClick="BuGetAge"
        android:text="Show Age"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="277dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="135dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

How can I make it to appear in the right place?

[image: picture of the emulator]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you absolutely need to use constraint layout? If not, you can use a relative layout, and use layout_centerHorizontal and layout_centerVertical like this:

```java
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="blah blah"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="press"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/edittext"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks :D, this is my first app so I didn't know the relative layout thing , solved :)

Answer (score 6):

Select Component/Item(such as BUTTON) in activity_main.xml -> click on "Infer Constrains(as I show in attached file)"

Your item will take right place in ASE

Do same for the rest Component/Items

[image: Enjoy]

Answer (score 1):

Click on an element and click the Magic Wand icon in the toolbar above the design view to Infer Constraints so the element will not jump to the (0, 0) position at runtime.

[image]

Comment: Yes, wand did the trick, thanks.  What is it doing exactly?  What does it change in the code/xml ?

Comment: @sb4 No problem. The wand infers the constraints for the element based on where the programmer places it.

Answer (score 0):

tools:layout_editor_absoluteY and other attributes from tools namespace only have effect in layout editor. Your working code does not use these attributes, so your views are in upper left corner, because this is default. As noted above RelativeLayout or even LinearLayout suits better such simple layout.

Answer (score -1):

Just change:

`</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>`

to

`</RelativeLayout>`

Problem solved! Be happy :D

Comment: Are you sure just by changing the  Constraint to Relative will solve the problem? you also need to remove the constraints like  tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="129dp"  and required constraints

Comment: Google has been advising developers to use Constraint layout for improved performance (flat view hierarchy).